# Looking for a .doc to .txt program

Tags: apt

I'm looking for a program that can batch convert .doc to .txt that is not command line or Terminal.

Comment: In general search  google for {format}2{format}. csv2doc doc2csv xml2txt etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following out:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/docx2txt/

It's open source and terminal based.